# Load error calling Rcpp file from R then call back in it

Tags: r, rcpp, argv, rinside

I wrote a *R* program that calls `hello1()`, which is an *Rcpp* function contained in `demo2.cpp` program

```
library(Rcpp)
ssss <- function(dd)
{
    return(paste("hello ",dd))
}

sourceCpp(file='demo2.cpp')
currentpath <- "/home/xuyan/R/parallel/"
aaa <-hello1(0,currentpath)
print(aaa)
```

my `demo2.cpp` is :

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <string>
#include <RInside.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int  hello1(int argc,string path)
{
    const char *argv[] = {path.c_str()};
    RInside R(argc,argv);
    R["txt"] = "Hello, world!\n";     

    R["sourcer"] = "demo.r";
    R.parseEvalQ("source(sourcer)");
    string str = Rcpp::as<string>(R.parseEval("ssss(txt)"));
    cout << "result is" << str << endl;
    return(111);
}
```

I've tried to launch this script with:

```
Rscript demo.r
```

I receive the following error:

> Error in
>   dyn.load("/tmp/RtmpZl0JKp/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-0.12.10/sourcecpp_90cc33eafd15/sourceCpp_2.so")
>   : 
>         unable to load shared object '/tmp/RtmpZl0JKp/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-0.12.10/sourcecpp_90cc33eafd15/sourceCpp_2.so':
>         /tmp/RtmpZl0JKp/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-0.12.10/sourcecpp_90cc33eafd15/sourceCpp_2.so:
>   undefined symbol: _ZN7RInsideD1Ev
>       Calls: sourceCpp -> source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> dyn.load
>       Execution halted

In fact, I want to solve slowness of *R*'s `for` loop.  I have an *R* program that has a large `for` loop and it execute very slowly. So, I want to change that `for` loop from *R* to *C++* code. Within the `for` loop, I call many *R* functions. So, I need to call from *C++* code to *R* program.  Thus, the order is *R* to *C++* to *R*, that is *R* to *Rcpp* to *Rinside*, am I wrong?

Why?

Answer (score 2):

You should *not* create a new session of *R* from within C++ given that you already have an active *R* session. With this being said, **do *NOT* include both `Rcpp.h` and `RInside.h`**. In this case, you should only use `Rcpp.h`.

So, simply use:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int  hello1(int argc, string path)
{
    const char *argv[] = {path.c_str()};
    return(111);
}
```

---

#### Edit 1

Per a later comment that was deleted, I think you want to use some *R* function within *C++*. To do that use *Rcpp*'s `Function` class. Make sure to load the *R* function into memory first by running the declaration. After doing this, then compile the following *C++* code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::CharacterVector hello1()
{
    Rcpp::Function some_r_func("ssss");

    return some_r_func("a");
}
```

---

#### Final Edit

> In fact, I want to solve slowness of R's for loop. I have an R program that has a large for loop and it execute very slowly. So, I want to change that for loop from R to C++ code. Within the for loop, I call many R functions. So, I need to call from C++ code to R program. Thus, the order is R to C++ to R, that is R to Rcpp to Rinside, am I wrong?

The issue with just switching a loop that calls *R* functions from *R* to *C++* and expecting a speed up is incorrect. The same loop must then reach out each time it encounters an *R* function and communicate with the *R* session. In essence, it effectively pauses the *C++* code, waits for the *R* code to execute and result, and then resume *C++* shell.

The only way to effectively speed up code in this paradigm is to completely write **all** of the *R* functions in *C++* and then call their *C++* equivalents within the C++ `for` loop.

See my previous remarks for "R to Rcpp to Rinside", which is again a NO. Never do this. Period. Only "R to Rcpp" or "C++ to RInside" are viable.

Comment: If I could upvote this a dozen times I would, promise!